# Passing a parameter form PHP HTML form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, parameter-passing, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using WordPress and Gravity Forms plugin and I am trying to pass a parameter from a third party provider to a Gravity Form with [Dynamic Population](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Using_Dynamic_Population) from another page, using the below code

```
<form method="post" name="goToForm" action="http://www.example.com/?page_id=123">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="Hello">
    <input type="submit" name="fromSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note that the above `http://www.example.com/?page_id=123` is the Gravity Form URL.

the closest solution I found is using the [HOOK](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_value_$parameter_name) method, but still I want to know how can I call the custom function that is created in `functions.php` using the HOOK approach from post and pass the parameter.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to pass the parameters on the form url?

You can accomplish this in 2 ways:

URL: http://www.example.com/?page_id=123

1. You can add a hidden field in the form. In the advanced section of the field, select Allow field to be populated dynamically and add the parameter name. So example I want to get the page_id:

[image]

After saving your form, inspect the hidden field and you should see it's value as `123`

2. You can add a hook function:

   `add_filter('gform_field_value_page_id', 'my_custom_population_function');
   function my_custom_population_function($value){
       return $value'; //or do what ever you want with it
   }`

If you want to add the page title or id automatically to the form:

1. Add a hidden field, in the advanced section of the field, add this `{embed_post:ID}` (Post ID) to the default value. OR
2. Add a hidden field, in the advanced section of the field, add this `{embed_post:post_title}` (Post Title) to the default value.

**Edit**

The user is looking for http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission

You can get your fields/parameters from your form and then save it to your database, update a Wordpress page/post or send it to a third party service provider.

I'm not too sure what user would like to do with the parameter, so I'll show an example of sending it to a third party provider:

- We want our entry field numbers so we can get the correct fields:

  ```
  /* Getting correct field numbers */

  add_action("gform_after_submission", "post_to_third_party", 10, 2);

  function post_to_third_party($entry, $form){
      // Lets get the IDs of the relevant fields and prepare an email message
      $message = print_r($entry, true);
      // In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
      $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
      // Send
      mail('you@domain.com', 'Getting the Gravity Form Field IDs', $message);
  }
  ```

You should get something like this in your mail:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 64
        [form_id] => 5
        [date_created] => 2014-07-02 13:27:00
        [is_starred] => 0
        [is_read] => 0
        [ip] => ::1
        [source_url] => http://localhost/
        [post_id] =>
        [currency] => USD
        [payment_status] =>
        [payment_date] =>
        [transaction_id] =>
        [payment_amount] =>
        [payment_method] =>
        [is_fulfilled] =>
        [created_by] => 1
        [transaction_type] =>
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3)
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153
    Safari/537.36
        [status] => active
        [1] => Name
        [4] => Parameter
    )
```

Where `[1] => Name` is a Name field and I entered Name for testing and `[4] => Parameter` is the parameter field with a default value of Parameter.

- After we have our correct field numbers, we can then submit it to the third party provider, I'm using curl in this example:

  ```
  /* Submitting to thirdparty.com */

  add_action("gform_after_submission", "post_to_third_party", 10, 2);

  function post_to_third_party($entry, $form){

  //Submitting to thirdparty.com using curl
  function post_to_url($url, $data) {
       $fields = '';
       foreach($data as $key => $value) {
       $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
       }
       rtrim($fields, '&');
       $post = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //if you want headers
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/xml");
       $result = curl_exec($post); 

       //If there's an error

       if($result === false)
          {
              echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
              echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
       }

       curl_close($post);
  }

  if($form["id"] == 1){//Form ID
      //Lets get the fields to match submission to thirdparty.com
      $data = array(
           "FirstName" =>     $entry["1"],
           "ParameterName" =>     $entry["4"]
      );

          post_to_url("http://thirdparty.com", $data);
  }


   }
  ```

If you want the hook to work for a specific form `gform_after_submission_1` will work for form id 1 only.

Comment: many thanks for your help, I already created the hidden field and set the parameter, but I want to send the parameter and call this page (where the gravity form exist) from another page, so I though of using html form method as I explained above. please  note that the extension of the URL `/?page_id=123` is a `WordPress` generated and its the reference to the target page not the parameter. Any Suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Oh ok I see, there's a way of doing that. I used page_id as an example. I'll edit my answer!

Comment: @user2079954 please see my edit. I dont know what you want to do with the parameter, but the `gform_after_submission` hook will help you get the value

Comment: thanks again for your support, please be informed that I mean to pass the parameter from any other third party provider to gravity form, and for that I tried using the html form to call the gravity form and submit the parameter

Comment: @user2079954 I dont think there is any hook to auto submit the gravity form with the parameter from a third party provider. It looks like you want to save the info and it's not possible with Gravity forms unless you do some hard coding on it. I highly suggest writing out a script in php to store the info and save it to your database and then add a Wordpress backend page for viewing the entries stored.